# C# Passing custom objects to Web Method using System.Web.Webclient

Tags: c#, json, web-services, webmethod, webservice-client

Web server side;

```
[Serializable]
public class product
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}


[WebMethod]
public static string testmethod(product pr)
{
    if (pr == null)
    return "parameter is null";
    return "Succesfull! Parameters you sent : " + pr.code +", "+ pr.name +","+ pr.description;
}
```

Client Side

```
    void WebService_Test()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                product pr = new product();
                pr.code = "LY700";
                pr.name = "Lenovo Y700";
                pr.description = "notebook";

                string pars = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pr, Formatting.Indented);
                string postUrl = "http://192.168.0.110/integration.aspx/testmethod"; 
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
                string result = client.UploadString(postUrl, "POST", pars);
                Console.Write(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.Message); }
        }
    }
```

I can send or return back string parameters succesfully, but I have to use object as parameter like this example I created above. But it says, The remote server returned 500 (Internal Server Error)
what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Check if `pr` is null in the `testmethod`, if so the server did not parse the request properly..

Comment: Madushan, but it is not null you see in this code sample, this is not the reason.

Comment: Just want to confirm if your client's data is parsed correctly by the server. You can't find what's wrong with your code if you assume your code it correct.

Comment: Madushan, I tried what you said also, and I edit the post. result is same, do you have an example using object parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some hours finally I found it!

Problem was here:

```
string result = client.UploadString(postUrl, "POST", pars);
```

it must be such as,

```
product pr = new product();
// pr definitons..
string par = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pr, Formatting.Indented);
string result = client.UploadString(postUrl, "POST", "{pr:"+ par + "}");
```

Also be sure you are using the same parameter name as you defined in webmethod input parameter. otherwise you will get error.